# Using slice function for breadcrumb routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having few URL paths in our project as below:-

```
hostname:port/abc
hostname:port/def
hostname:port/ghi
```

Where breadcrumb value of `ghi component` is `abc/def/ghi`.

I am trying to achieve navigable breadcrumb for each component in breadcrumb which will take dynamically redirect me to **hostname:port`/breadcrumbitem`** as mentioned in above URL.

I am passing path value from each component to breadcrumb component in this pattern:- `<JarvisBreadCrumb path={props.path} />`.

Some example values of `props.path` can be considered as `/abc` , `/def` , `/ghi`

I have came up with below logic for making each breadcrumb item clickable to `hostname:port/clickableBreadcrumbItem` but it is not working as expected. Below is the snippet of code of breadcrumb component where breadcrumb items are generated.

```
return (
    <>
      <div className="bread-crumb">
        <ul className="bread-crumb-list">
          <li>
            <NavLink exact to="/homepage" activeClassName="active">
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon="home" color="#30343f" size="lg" />
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li className="bread-crumb-list-items">
            {/* {props.PageTitle} */}
            {pathnames.map((names, index) => {
              const routeTo = `/${pathnames
                .slice(0)
                .join("/")
                .split(" ")
                .join("")}`;
              const isLast = index === pathnames.length - 1;
              console.log("inside map function");
              console.log("value of routeTo is " + routeTo);
              console.log(typeof routeTo);
              console.log("value of isLast is " + isLast);
              console.log("value of path is " + props.path);
              return isLast ? (
                <p key={names}>{names}</p>
              ) : (
                <NavLink key={names} to={props.path}>
                  {routeTo}
                </NavLink>
              );
            })}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Is there any way I can break the breadcrumb path `/abc/def/ghi/jkl` into separate individual paths `/abc`, `/def`, `/ghi` and pass it to the URL as `hostname:port/abc`, `hostname:port/def`, `hostname:port/ghi`

Note: Excluding the last part from the path `/abc/def/ghi/jkl` i.e. `/jkl`. This path `/jkl` will be just a plain text which will not be clickable

**Edit-1(Answering Drew Reese):-**

Path value I am receiving in component are separate as I have mentioned above when I said

> Some example values of `props.path` can be considered as `/abc` , `/def` , `/ghi`.

In order to make it more clear

For visual perspective in frontend :- We need to combine them dynamically as `/abc/def/ghi`, this comnbining of path will be dependant on the path which we are currently in.

For navigation perspective

If I hover and click over `/abc` it should redirect us to `hostname:port/abc`

If I hover and click over `/def` it should redirect us to `hostname:port/def`

If I hover and click over `/ghi` it should redirect us to `hostname:port/ghi`

Comment: Is `/abc/def/ghi/jkl` a string value you can split on "/"? It's a bit unclear if the paths are already separate (since you join them) or if you have some `"/abc/def/ghi/jkl"` string.

Comment: @DrewReese I have update few things above, in order to make things more clear. Let me know if I was able to answer your queries.

Comment: Wouldn't `names` in the map callback be the path you are asking to link to? I feel this is too obvious so perhaps I'm still not understanding your code or your request.

Comment: Don't you mean "and pass it to the URL as hostname:port/abc, hostname:port/abc/def, hostname:port/abc/def/ghi" instead?

Comment: What does `pathnames` contain?

Comment: "but it is not working as expected" What exactly isn't working? What is the result you're getting?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, `names` in map callback is the value I want to link to URL. But also in parallel to that I want all of the path to be concatenated so that each path `abc`, `def`, `ghi` has its own URL as I have mentioned in question.

Comment: Answer from @Someone Special has done 90% of my work. But its just that last path is also clickable as per his solution and I want to have last path (which in this case is `ghi`) as a plain text

Comment: I guess it isn't clear to me why or how concatenating a path segment, i.e. `"/abc"`, to a base URL isn't working, and I don't think you've done a good enough job of explaining your use case and what you expect the result to be. Is the issue even the URL creation or is it the bread crump creation, or something else entirely? It sounds like all you need is something like `"/abc/def/ghi/jkl".split("/").map(path => <NavLink to={`${url}/${path}`}>{path}</Navlink>`, accounting for the last being text instead of a link, but again, this seems entirely too obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of your objective, but does this answer your question?

```js
const str = `/abc/def/ghi/ijk`

const splitPath = (path) => {
  const array = path.split('/');

  let i = 1;
  let final = []
  while (i < array.length) {
    final.push(`/${array.slice(1,i+1).join('/').toString()}` )
    i++;
  }
  return final
}



splitPath(str).map( (item, index)=> console.log(item))
```

Edited since poster's question wasn't clear.
**Updated** to check for last item

```js
const str = `/abc/def/ghi/ijk`
const hostname = `hostname:8000`
const array = str.split('/')

array.map( (item, index) => {
  const path = `${hostname}/${item}`
  
  console.log( index < array.length-1 ? `<a href=/${path}>${item}</a>` : `<span>${item}</span>`)
  return
})
```

Comment: I have tried to make my objective more clear in the question. Can you please have a look at it now? And let me know if I was able to make it clear to you?

Comment: what's wrong with just using  .split('/') then map through and create the hyperlinks?

Comment: edited the answer, you have to substitude `console.log` with your own html elements.

Comment: I am actually able to perform the thing which I am expecting. But only thing I am looking at right now is. I don't want last path `/ijk` to be clickable. I want it as a plain text concatenated at last of breadcrumb path.

Comment: updated code to check `array.length` against `index` to find last item

Comment: This actually worked the way I wanted it to. Thanks for your efforts@Someone Special